# Spring Boot multiple profiles DataSource

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, yaml, datasource

I am writing a Spring Boot application with two Oracle datasources - Here is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
    profiles: test
datasource:
  app2:
       url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//rap-vin:1521/APP221
       username: user2
       password: pwd2
       driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  app:
       url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//eap10-san:1522/APP22
       username: user
       password: pwd
       driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
application:
  app:
       url: example.com/app
```

I've a DBConfiguration class that looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.app")
    public DataSource appDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.app2")
    public DataSource app2DataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return ds;
    }
}
```

And then I've a test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DBConfiguration.class)
public class Test {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateAPP;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateAPP2;
    //private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(final DataSource appDataSource,
                @Qualifier("app2DataSource") final DataSource app2DataSource) {
            this.jdbcTemplateAPP = new JdbcTemplate(appDataSource);
            this.jdbcTemplateAPP2 = new JdbcTemplate(app2DataSource);
        }

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        int count= jdbcTemplateAPP.queryForObject("select count(*) from parm", int.class);

        Assert.assertTrue(count==1);
    }
}
```

But whenever I run the test I get the db urls as null.
What am I doing wrong? Also how should I read in the application.app url?Appreciate your help with this - (fyi I'm a Spring newbie)
The error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:305) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:390) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:480) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:490) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:496) [spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.tgt.trans.intl.batchtest.mib.tests.MIB022Test.testJob(MIB022Test.java:35) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

first,

did u activate profile "test" by VM argument or somehow?
your yml seems just define the profile ,but it still has not activated.

if you wanna make active the profile "test" in yml 
you should write below

```
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: test
```

or put this to VM

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

second,

in the test class
both of appDataSource and app2DataSource will be injected by appDataSource.

perhaps you don't intention this
so if you want to inject app2DataSource to app2DataSource
should write below

```
@Qualifier("app2DataSource") final DataSource app2DataSource
```

finally 
if you want to use content of yml(like a application.app.url)in ur test class
put

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.app")
```

on ur class and define variable like this

```
private String url;
```

Comment: thanks - I fixed my post to include app2datasource - what do you mean when you say " if you want to use application.app in ur test " - which class is that? do I've to create one?

Comment: I should say "if you want to use contents of yml in your test class"  
and answer is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Comment: I see - but the error I'm getting is while reading the datasource urls - I'm not even using the application url.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by editing:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

...
```

to:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DBConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
...
```